# Devise Confirmation Error with Heroku and Sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I'm new to rails, and am trying to use the devise :confirmable feature. Everything works great in development, but in production, none of the confirmation functionality is working. When a new user tries to sign up, heroku just throws the error "Something went wrong." My reset password mailer is working beautifully in production, so I don't know why the confirmable one isn't.

Looking at the logs, it seems that the error it is throwing is

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x007f38f5789580>):
```

In my environments.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_startstls_auto => true
}
```

The migration I ran to add confirmable:

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at,       :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at , :datetime
    add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string

    add_index  :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index  :users, :confirmation_token

    remove_column :users, :unconfirmed_email
    remove_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at
    remove_column :users, :confirmed_at
    remove_column :users, :confirmation_token
  end
end
```

I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` as well.
How can I fix this?

Comment: could you check if the migration ran successfully on heroku. use `heroku run rails c` and access the rails console and check the fields for the User model

Comment: @Alfie the migration did work on heroku, and I can see the fields for each user.

Comment: Just in case, can you restart the heroku app

Comment: @Alfie Wow, such a simple solution. This worked for me, thanks :)

Comment: Awesome, glad to help.